# WindowFromPoint returns handle for controls, but I only want the main window

Tags: winapi

I'm writing a window spy type thing to add a feature to an application I have. I've got all the code working, but sometimes WindowFromPoint returns a handle for a control instead of the containing window. For my purposes, I am only concerned with the main containing window. Is there a way for me exclude controls? Or possible detect that the result is a control and recurse upward until I reach the containing window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for the WS_CHILD flag ([`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with 'GWL_STYLE') and if it's there call [`GetAncestor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with 'GA_ROOT' as 'gaFlags'.

Comment: I'm doing this in C# and pinvoke has `GetWindowLongPtr` returning an `IntPtr`. Since `WS_CHILD` is a long, how can I convert them into the same format in order to check the flag?

Comment: The window style is just a 32 bit number (GWL_* are 32 bit, GWLP_* are pointer sized)

Comment: @Anders The window styles are listed as longs (64 bit). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  `ToInt64()` worked to do the flag check against `WS_CHILD`.

Comment: @unholysampler: Windows is LLP64 so a long is actually 32bit, but GetWindowLongPtr returns a LONG_PTR and it is pointer sized, however, windows style bits are all in the 32bit range (The older GetWindowLong function documentation sort of confirms this "If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle, this function has been superseded by the GetWindowLongPtr function")